# How do I sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

What I want to do seems pretty simple, but I can't find any answers on the web. I have an `NSMutableArray` of objects, and let's say they are 'Person' objects. I want to sort the `NSMutableArray` by Person.birthDate which is an `NSDate`.

I think it has something to do with this method:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(???)];
```

In Java I would make my object implement Comparable, or use Collections.sort with an inline custom comparator...how on earth do you do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2349, accepted):

### Compare method

Either you implement a compare-method for your object:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)otherObject {
    return [self.birthDate compare:otherObject.birthDate];
}

NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

### NSSortDescriptor (better)

or usually even better:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                           ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

You can easily sort by multiple keys by adding more than one to the array. Using custom comparator-methods is possible as well. Have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

### Blocks (shiny!)

There's also the possibility of sorting with a block since Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *a, Person *b) {
    return [a.birthDate compare:b.birthDate];
}];
```

## Performance

The `-compare:` and block-based methods will be quite a bit faster, in general, than using `NSSortDescriptor` as the latter relies on KVC.  The primary advantage of the `NSSortDescriptor` method is that it provides a way to define your sort order using data, rather than code, which makes it easy to e.g. set things up so users can sort an `NSTableView` by clicking on the header row.

Comment: The first example has a bug: You compare the birthDate instance variable in one object with the other object itself, rather than its birthDate variable.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! Funny that nobody else noticed before I got 75 upvotes for it.

Comment: Because this is the accepted answer, and therefore probably considered definitive by most users, it might be helpful to add a 3rd, block-based example so that users will be aware it exists too.

Comment: @orange80: I tried that. I don't own a Mac any more, so it would be nice if you could look at the code.

Comment: You can also declare the parameters of the block with the correct type already, reducing the sorting to: [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Person* a, Person* b) { return [a.birthDate compare:b.birthDate]; }]

Comment: @fishinear: Are you sure? I've haven't used blocks yet myself, but looking at other examples it seems that everyone uses id as the arguments. Example: [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227702/sortedarrayusingcomparator-int), [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054921/changing-the-sort-order-of-nsarray-sortedarrayusingcomparator).

Comment: In the case where birthDate is null and you want those to show up at the end of the sorted array you can do this: NSDate *first = [(Person *)a birthDate] ? [a birthDate]:[NSDate distantFuture];

Comment: so how about case insensitive sort on an nsstring object comparison using second method??

Comment: @Lithu: Did you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's basically directly in there. If you don't find out how to do it, ask in a new question.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly : yup worked it out by docs..frgt to update the cmnt  :)

Comment: k here is the answer for wht i hav asked ,ie about case sensitive nd case insensitive sort.there is one more method in sort descriptor which defines the selector :-   sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

Comment: Thank you! That's a solution for issue about ordering accented characters in SQLite.

Comment: If you have a `NSMutableArray` i prefer to use the methodes `sortUsingDescriptors` , `sortUsingFunction` or `sortUsingSelector`. As far as the array is mutable I usually don't need a sorted copy.

Comment: I have used block option for sort. it's work great. but i have another problem i have to sort an array using condition. like i have two values "Company" and "Date". if the company name is same then it check date which would be latest it first sort can you help me out ?

Comment: What if I have an array with latitude and longitude and I want to sort by distance from userLocation. I've calculated the distance to each.  Do I create a new array with the distance value?

Comment: @marciokoko: Open a new questions, comments are not a good place for this. :)

Comment: Thanks Georg, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879486/how-do-i-access-a-custom-object-in-memory-from-a-view-controller/14880214#14880214

Comment: Just wanted to add - the answer to the question asked by @HiRen isn't for another question. This is exactly what the sort descriptors in this example are for. Maybe this post should explain that you can use multiple sort descriptors to sort by many keys?

Comment: @Accatyyc: I added a small paragraph about it. I didn't want to increase the complexity of the answer too much.

Comment: also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844031/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-using-sortedarrayusingdescriptors/1845165#1845165

Comment: this should be updated to include literals, so future people looking at this code can see updated syntax, and how it's now being done.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse but its potentially be worth noting that `sortedUsingComparator` sorts in-place with a `NSMutableArray`, potentially a more common use case.

Comment: And what is the best/fastest sorting method?

Comment: The third one is the best option? @GeorgSchölly

Comment: @Karen: It depends. Use the `compare` method if there is a natural ordering between your objects. If it's a simple comparison, use a `block`. And finally if your comparison is tricky and uses lots of logic, an `NSSortDescriptor` probably makes the most sense.

Comment: I love the block as well, I've used it in a couple of projects I was working on, and they never failed me! Block to the rescue! :) ( and Georg )

Comment: Where does the compare method go?  In the implementation of the custom object being sorted in the NSMutableArray, or in the implementation of the class doing the sorting?  I sense it should be in the custom object's implementation (from the self.birthdate), but the formatting of the answer makes it seem like it's the same .m file as the call to sort the array, so I wanted to check to make sure.  From the standpoint of a programming beginner, it's not obvious at all where to put snippets of code even if it might seem second nature to a vet.

Comment: You're right, it goes into the implementation of the custom object.

Answer (score 113):

See the `NSMutableArray` method [`sortUsingFunction:context:`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCEEJD)

You will need to set up a *compare* function which takes two objects (of type `Person`, since you are comparing two `Person` objects) and a *context* parameter.

The two objects are just instances of `Person`. The third object is a string, e.g. @"birthDate".

This function returns an `NSComparisonResult`: It returns `NSOrderedAscending` if `PersonA.birthDate` < `PersonB.birthDate`. It will return `NSOrderedDescending` if `PersonA.birthDate` > `PersonB.birthDate`. Finally, it will return `NSOrderedSame` if `PersonA.birthDate` == `PersonB.birthDate`.

This is rough pseudocode; you will need to flesh out what it means for one date to be "less", "more" or "equal" to another date (such as comparing seconds-since-epoch etc.):

```
NSComparisonResult compare(Person *firstPerson, Person *secondPerson, void *context) {
  if ([firstPerson birthDate] < [secondPerson birthDate])
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  else if ([firstPerson birthDate] > [secondPerson birthDate])
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  else 
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

If you want something more compact, you can use ternary operators:

```
NSComparisonResult compare(Person *firstPerson, Person *secondPerson, void *context) {
  return ([firstPerson birthDate] < [secondPerson birthDate]) ? NSOrderedAscending : ([firstPerson birthDate] > [secondPerson birthDate]) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Inlining could perhaps speed this up a little, if you do this a lot.

Comment: Using sortUsingFunction:context: is probably the most c-ish way and definitly the most unreadable one.

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with it, but I think there are now much better alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think it would be any less readable to someone from a Java background who might be looking for something similar to Java's abstract Comparator class, which implements compare(Type obj1, Type obj2).

Comment: I think the biggest stumbling block to using sortUsingFunction for some one with out a solid C background would be: a) realising it wants a function pointer; b) get used to the idea of a function pointer; c) parse the function pointer so as to construct the required function.

Comment: I get the sense a couple of you are looking for any reason whatsoever to criticize this perfectly fine answer, even if that criticism has very little technical merit. Weird.

Comment: @Georg, the problem with your answer above, and the advantages to Alex's method here, is that you get one compare method per class. So if you need to compare on multiple criteria, you must use `sortUsingFunction:content:`, Right?

Comment: @Yar: Either you can use the solution I provided in the first paragraph, or you use multiple sort descriptors. *sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:* takes an array of sort descriptors as argument.

Comment: @Jeroen Hi! When you are going to reject an edit, just reject it, don't click "improve" if you don't actually mean to improve the edit. Rejecting the edits here was a good call, but by going through improve you've created two nonsensical revisions to the question.

Comment: I know, you are right, I had a moment of confusion here because of doing 3 things at once. Won't happen again ;)

Answer (score 66):

I did this in iOS 4 using a block.
Had to cast the elements of my array from id to my class type.
In this case it was a class called Score with a property called points.

Also you need to decide what to do if the elements of your array are not the right type, for this example I just returned `NSOrderedSame`, however in my code I though an exception.

```
NSArray *sorted = [_scores sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){
    if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[Score class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[Score class]]) {
        Score *s1 = obj1;
        Score *s2 = obj2;

        if (s1.points > s2.points) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if (s1.points < s2.points) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
    }

    // TODO: default is the same?
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

return sorted;
```

PS: This is sorting in descending order.

Comment: You don't actually need the "(Score *)" casts in there, you can just do "Score *s1 = obj1;" because id will happily cast to anything without warning from the compiler :-)

Comment: right orange80 `downcasting` doesn't requires a cast before the weak variable.

Comment: You should sort nil vs. not-nil to the top or bottom consistently, so the default end return might be `return ((!obj1 && !obj2) ? NSOrderedSame : (obj1 ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending))`

Comment: heh Chris, i tried this code, I do hv a refresh in my program.. for the first time i does correct job, got a descending order output.. but when i refresh.( execute the same code with same data ) it changed the order, it was not descending.. Say i hv 4 objects in my array, 3 hv same data, 1 is differed.

Comment: If you actually expect objects that are not of the "Score" class, you need to sort them a bit more careful. Otherwise you have a situation where other == score1 < score2 == other which is inconsistent and could lead to trouble. You could return a value that implies Score objects sort before all other objects, and all other objects sort equal to each other.

Answer (score 31):

I tried all, but this worked for me. In a class I have another class named "`crimeScene`", and want to sort by a property of "`crimeScene`".

This works like a charm:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"crimeScene.distance" ascending:YES];
[self.arrAnnotations sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
```

Answer (score 30):

Starting in iOS 4 you can also use blocks for sorting.

For this particular example I'm assuming that the objects in your array have a 'position' method, which returns an `NSInteger`.

```
NSArray *arrayToSort = where ever you get the array from... ;
NSComparisonResult (^sortBlock)(id, id) = ^(id obj1, id obj2) 
{
    if ([obj1 position] > [obj2 position]) 
    { 
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 position] < [obj2 position]) 
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
};
NSArray *sorted = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortBlock];
```

Note: the "sorted" array will be autoreleased.

Answer (score 28):

There is a missing step in [Georg Schölly's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it/805589#805589), but it works fine then.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

// added the 's' because time was wasted when I copied and pasted and it failed without the 's' in sortedArrayUsingDescriptors

Comment: The method call is actually "sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:", with an 's' at the end.

Answer (score 21):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Thanks, it's working fine...

Answer (score 19):

Your `Person` objects need to implement a method, say `compare:` which takes another `Person` object, and return `NSComparisonResult` according to the relationship between the 2 objects.

Then you would call `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` with `@selector(compare:)` and it should be done.

There are other ways, but as far as I know there is no Cocoa-equiv of the `Comparable` interface. Using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` is probably the most painless way to do it.

Answer (score 12):

iOS 4 blocks will save you :)

```
featuresArray = [[unsortedFeaturesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b)  
{
    DMSeatFeature *first = ( DMSeatFeature* ) a;
    DMSeatFeature *second = ( DMSeatFeature* ) b;

    if ( first.quality == second.quality )
        return NSOrderedSame;
    else
    {
        if ( eSeatQualityGreen  == m_seatQuality || eSeatQualityYellowGreen == m_seatQuality || eSeatQualityDefault  == m_seatQuality )
        {
            if ( first.quality < second.quality )
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            else
                return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else // eSeatQualityRed || eSeatQualityYellow
        {
            if ( first.quality > second.quality )
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            else
                return NSOrderedDescending;
        } 
    }
}] retain];
```

http://sokol8.blogspot.com/2011/04/sorting-nsarray-with-blocks.html a bit of description

Answer (score 10):

For `NSMutableArray`, use the `sortUsingSelector` method. It sorts it-place, without creating a new instance.

Comment: Just an update: I too was looking for something that sorted the mutable array in place, there are now "sortUsing" equivalent methods for all the "sortedArrayUsing" methods as of iOS 7. Such as `sortUsingComparator:`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following generic method for your purpose. It should solve your issue.

```
//Called method
-(NSMutableArray*)sortArrayList:(NSMutableArray*)arrDeviceList filterKeyName:(NSString*)sortKeyName ascending:(BOOL)isAscending{
    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKeyName ascending:isAscending];
    [arrDeviceList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
    return arrDeviceList;
}

//Calling method
[self sortArrayList:arrSomeList filterKeyName:@"anything like date,name etc" ascending:YES];
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're just sorting an array of `NSNumbers`, you can sort them with 1 call:

```
[arrayToSort sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

That works because the objects in the array (`NSNumber` objects) implement the compare method. You could do the same thing for `NSString` objects, or even for an array of custom data objects that implement a compare method.

Here's some example code using comparator blocks. It sorts an array of dictionaries where each dictionary includes a number in a key "sort_key".

```
#define SORT_KEY @\"sort_key\"

[anArray sortUsingComparator: 
 ^(id obj1, id obj2) 
  {
  NSInteger value1 = [[obj1 objectForKey: SORT_KEY] intValue];
  NSInteger value2 = [[obj2 objectForKey: SORT_KEY] intValue];
  if (value1 > value2) 
{
  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
  }

  if (value1 < value2) 
{
  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
  }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
 }];
```

The code above goes through the work of getting an integer value for each sort key and comparing them, as an illustration of how to do it. Since `NSNumber` objects implement a compare method, it could be rewritten much more simply:

```
 #define SORT_KEY @\"sort_key\"

[anArray sortUsingComparator: 
^(id obj1, id obj2) 
 {
  NSNumber* key1 = [obj1 objectForKey: SORT_KEY];
  NSNumber* key2 = [obj2 objectForKey: SORT_KEY];
  return [key1 compare: key2];
 }];
```

or the body of the comparator could even be distilled down to 1 line:

```
  return [[obj1 objectForKey: SORT_KEY] compare: [obj2 objectForKey: SORT_KEY]];
```

I tend to prefer simple statements and lots of temporary variables because the code is easier to read, and easier to debug. The compiler optimizes away the temporary variables anyway, so there is no advantage to the all-in-one-line version.

Answer (score 8):

You use NSSortDescriptor to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortingDescriptor;
 sortingDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                       ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 7):

I've used **sortUsingFunction::** in some of my projects:

```
int SortPlays(id a, id b, void* context)
{
    Play* p1 = a;
    Play* p2 = b;
    if (p1.score<p2.score) 
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (p1.score>p2.score) 
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

...
[validPlays sortUsingFunction:SortPlays context:nil];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
-(NSMutableArray*) sortArray:(NSMutableArray *)toBeSorted 
{
  NSArray *sortedArray;
  sortedArray = [toBeSorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) 
  {
    return [a compare:b];
 }];
 return [sortedArray mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: why to pass in a mutable array, when a new array is returned. why to create a wrapper at all?

Answer (score 7):

I have created a small library of category methods, called [Linq to ObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC), that makes this sort of thing more easy. Using the [sort](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#sort) method with a key selector, you can sort by `birthDate` as follows:

```
NSArray* sortedByBirthDate = [input sort:^id(id person) {
    return [person birthDate];
}]
```

Comment: You ought to call it "[LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) to [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)".

Answer (score 7):

I just done multi level sorting based on custom requirement.

//sort the values

```
    [arrItem sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (id a, id b){

    ItemDetail * itemA = (ItemDetail*)a;
    ItemDetail* itemB =(ItemDetail*)b;

    //item price are same
    if (itemA.m_price.m_selling== itemB.m_price.m_selling) {

        NSComparisonResult result=  [itemA.m_itemName compare:itemB.m_itemName];

        //if item names are same, then monogramminginfo has to come before the non monograme item
        if (result==NSOrderedSame) {

            if (itemA.m_monogrammingInfo) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }else{
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //asscending order
    return itemA.m_price.m_selling > itemB.m_price.m_selling;
}];
```

https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/ios/multilevelsortinginiosobjectivec

Answer (score 5):

Sorting `NSMutableArray` is very simple:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToFilter =
     [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Photoshop",
                                       @"Flex",
                                       @"AIR",
                                       @"Flash",
                                       @"Acrobat", nil] autorelease];

NSMutableArray *productsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray array] autorelease];

for (NSString *products in arrayToFilter) {
    if (fliterText &&
        [products rangeOfString:fliterText
                        options:NSLiteralSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].length == 0)

        [productsToRemove addObject:products];
}
[arrayToFilter removeObjectsInArray:productsToRemove];
```

Answer (score 5):

**Sort using NSComparator**

If we want to sort custom objects we need to provide `NSComparator`, which is used to compare custom objects. The block returns an `NSComparisonResult` value to denote the ordering of the two objects. So in order to sort whole array `NSComparator` is used in following way.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Employee *e1, Employee *e2){
    return [e1.firstname compare:e2.firstname];    
}];
```

**Sorts Using NSSortDescriptor**
Let’s assume, as an example, that we have an array containing instances of a custom class, Employee has attributes  firstname, lastname and age. The following example illustrates how to create an NSSortDescriptor that can be used to sort the array contents in ascending order by the age key.

```
NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

**Sort using Custom Comparisons**
Names are strings, and when you sort strings to present to the user you should always use a localized comparison. Often you also want to perform a case insensitive comparison. Here comes an example with (localizedStandardCompare:) to order the array by last and first name.

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
              initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor * firstNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
              initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[lastNameDescriptor, firstNameDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

For reference and detailed discussion please refer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html
http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-sort-nsarray-with-custom-objects/

Answer (score 4):

Swift's protocols and functional programming makes that very easy you just have to make your class conform to the Comparable protocol, implement the methods required by the protocol and then use the sorted(by: ) high order function to create a sorted array without need to use mutable arrays by the way.

```
class Person: Comparable {
    var birthDate: NSDate?
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.birthDate === rhs.birthDate || lhs.birthDate?.compare(rhs.birthDate as! Date) == .orderedSame
    }

    static func <(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.birthDate?.compare(rhs.birthDate as! Date) == .orderedAscending
    }

    static func >(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.birthDate?.compare(rhs.birthDate as! Date) == .orderedDescending
    }

}

let p1 = Person(name: "Sasha")
p1.birthDate = NSDate() 

let p2 = Person(name: "James")
p2.birthDate = NSDate()//he is older by miliseconds

if p1 == p2 {
    print("they are the same") //they are not
}

let persons = [p1, p2]

//sort the array based on who is older
let sortedPersons = persons.sorted(by: {$0 > $1})

//print sasha which is p1
print(persons.first?.name)
//print James which is the "older"
print(sortedPersons.first?.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I use "sortedArrayUsingComparator" to sort an array. Look at the below code.

```
contactArray = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:[contactSet allObjects]] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ContactListData *obj1, ContactListData *obj2) {
    NSString *obj1Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",obj1.contactName,obj1.contactSurname];
    NSString *obj2Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",obj2.contactName,obj2.contactSurname];
    return [obj1Str compare:obj2Str];
}];
```

Also my object is,

```
@interface ContactListData : JsonData
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * contactName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * contactSurname;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * contactPhoneNumber;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create sortDescriptor and then you can sort the nsmutablearray by using sortDescriptor like below.

```
 let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "birthDate", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.compare(_:)))
 let array = NSMutableArray(array: self.aryExist.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]))
 print(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Sort Array In Swift

---

For `Swifty` Person below is a very clean technique to achieve above goal for globally. Lets have an example custom class of `User` which have some attributes.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var createdDate: Date?
}
```

Now we have an array which we need to sort on the basis of `createdDate` either ascending and/or descending. So lets add a function for date comparison.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var createdDate: Date?
    func checkForOrder(_ otherUser: User, _ order: ComparisonResult) -> Bool {
        if let myCreatedDate = self.createdDate, let othersCreatedDate = otherUser.createdDate {
            //This line will compare both date with the order that has been passed.
            return myCreatedDate.compare(othersCreatedDate) == order
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Now lets have an `extension` of `Array` for `User`. In simple words lets add some methods only for those Array's which only have `User` objects in it.

```
extension Array where Element: User {
    //This method only takes an order type. i.e ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    func sortUserByDate(_ order: ComparisonResult) -> [User] {
        let sortedArray = self.sorted { (user1, user2) -> Bool in
            return user1.checkForOrder(user2, order)
        }
        return sortedArray
    }
}
```

**Usage for Ascending Order**

```
let sortedArray = someArray.sortUserByDate(.orderedAscending)
```

---

**Usage for Descending Order**

```
let sortedArray = someArray.sortUserByDate(.orderedAscending)
```

---

**Usage for Same Order**

```
let sortedArray = someArray.sortUserByDate(.orderedSame)
```

---

> Above method in `extension` will only be accessible if the `Array` is of type
>   `[User]` || `Array<User>`

Answer (score 2):

Use like this for nested objects,

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastRoute.to.lastname" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedPackages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[packages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]]];
```

lastRoute is one object and that object holds the to object, that to object hold the lastname string values.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift version: 5.1**

If you have a custom struct or class and want to sort them arbitrarily, you should call sort() using a trailing closure that sorts on a field you specify. Here's an example using an array of custom structs that sorts on a particular property:

```
    struct User {
        var firstName: String
    }

    var users = [
        User(firstName: "Jemima"),
        User(firstName: "Peter"),
        User(firstName: "David"),
        User(firstName: "Kelly"),
        User(firstName: "Isabella")
    ]

    users.sort {
        $0.firstName < $1.firstName
    }
```

**If you want to return a sorted array rather than sort it in place, use sorted() like this:**

```
    let sortedUsers = users.sorted {
        $0.firstName < $1.firstName
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  let sortedUsers = users.sorted {
    $0.firstName < $1.firstName
 }
```

Comment: The question is about NSMutableArray, not about Arrays collection in Swift

Answer (score -2):

```
NSMutableArray *stockHoldingCompanies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fortune1stock,fortune2stock,fortune3stock,fortune4stock,fortune5stock,fortune6stock , nil];

NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"companyName" ascending:NO];

[stockHoldingCompanies sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [stockHoldingCompanies objectEnumerator];

ForeignStockHolding *stockHoldingCompany;

NSLog(@"Fortune 6 companies sorted by Company Name");

    while (stockHoldingCompany = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@"===============================");
        NSLog(@"CompanyName:%@",stockHoldingCompany.companyName);
        NSLog(@"Purchase Share Price:%.2f",stockHoldingCompany.purchaseSharePrice);
        NSLog(@"Current Share Price: %.2f",stockHoldingCompany.currentSharePrice);
        NSLog(@"Number of Shares: %i",stockHoldingCompany.numberOfShares);
        NSLog(@"Cost in Dollars: %.2f",[stockHoldingCompany costInDollars]);
        NSLog(@"Value in Dollars : %.2f",[stockHoldingCompany valueInDollars]);
    }
    NSLog(@"===============================");
```